# How to enable changes in site.cfg

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using WinPython 2.7 and I have troubles with numpy configuration. My site.cfg is

```
[mkl]
include_dirs = C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include
library_dirs = C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64;C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/intel64
mkl_libs = mkl_lapack95_lp64,mkl_blas95_lp64,mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd
lapack_libs = mkl_lapack95_lp64,mkl_blas95_lp64,mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd
```

But variable, responsable for blas is

```
blas_opt_info={'libraries': ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd'], 'library_dirs': ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)], 'include_dirs': ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']}
```

So one path to MKL libraries is missing. How to fix it? How correctly use several library pathes? How to apply changes in site.cfg ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"variable, responsable for blas "*? Is that part of the output when you run `python setup.py config` from within the source directory?

Comment: There is several variables in __config__.py, one of them (blas_opt_info) contain flags for linking with blas libs